# Nonexistent right margin on float: right item?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've got this bit of HTML:

```html
<div id="content">
    <h1 id="prompt">What's on your mind?</h1>

    <form action="post.php" method="POST" id="message-form">
        <textarea placeholder="Type in anything you want to share. Anything at all."></textarea>
        <p>Feel free to type up to <span id="character-count">2000 characters</span>, or to use <a href="http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax">Markdown</a> formatting.</p>
        <input type="submit" class="submit button" value="Share" />
        <br class="clearfix" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```css
/* CSS Reset
-------------------------------------------*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

/* UI Elements
-------------------------------------------*/
.button {
    background-color: #ccc;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #ccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #ccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(white, #ccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white, #ccc);
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, #ccc);
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
    border-color: #666;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #bbb;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, white);
}

/* Content
-------------------------------------------*/
#content {
    margin: 10px;
}

/* Prompt
-------------------------------------------*/
#prompt {
    color: #888;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* Message Box
-------------------------------------------*/
#message-form {
    width: 600px;
}

#message-form textarea {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, Serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-height: 100px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    resize: vertical;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#message-form textarea:hover {
    border-color: #666;
}

#message-form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #3bf;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #3bf;
}

#message-form p {
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 3px;
}

#message-form .submit {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to float an element rightwards within a particular amount of space. This works, but there's about 10 pixels' space to the right of the button that don't appear to exist! It's not padding from the parent element, nor margin on the button as far as I can see... so where is it coming from? Below is an image of the problem, and the full code can be found at https://github.com/minitech/MiniTicket. **[Here's a demo on jsFiddle, too.](http://jsfiddle.net/pCNzX/show/)**

[image: Problem screenshot]

Sorry for the overload of code, but [I can't seem to reproduce the problem in a simple way](http://jsfiddle.net/KX7wd/).

Comment: Is there a working version of this running somewhere that we can run it?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Sorry, edited in. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/pCNzX/show/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that setting `width: 100%` and any amount of horizontal `padding` will cause your element to have a width beyond 100% (unless it's an `input` element, in which padding is applied inside of the element).

In your case, your `textarea` width is 610px. The submit button is properly floated to the far right of your 600px width container.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/KX7wd/1/

Replacement for padding in textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/KX7wd/2/

Comment: D'oh! I forgot I set padding on the <textarea>. :P (Accepting in 3 minutes...)

Comment: You could always use `box-sizing: border-box;`, which would allow you to keep both `width: 100%` and `padding` on your `textarea`. Keep in mind this [does not work in IE7 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing).

Comment: No, the problem is that it doesn't work on *any* version of Firefox :) I already put that in as a temporary fix since this problem doesn't exactly ruin the entire user experience, but I'm still trying to find a nicer solution.

Comment: You could always surround the `textarea` in a styled `label` and then apply the padding to the `label` so that you can use `width: 100%` on the `textarea`. The reason I choose `label` over any other element is because you can make it so if you click anywhere within `label` it will automatically select the `textarea`. I added a preview to my answer.

Comment: I suppose I'll do that instead. Too bad there's not a nice and simple solution :)